# How to write in Swift: [MyClass class]?

Tags: class, swift

I want to refer to a class in Swift. In Objective-C I have written this expression: `[MyClass class]` How does it work in Swift? I need it to assign it to a delegate.

I have tried this: `MyClass.class`, but get this error: *Expected member name following '.'*

Comment: You can't refer to a class in swift (it's not something you can access in code). What do you want to achieve? Why do you need [MyClass class]?

Comment: If you need the name of the class you can use `_stdlib_getTypeName(obj)` or `_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(obj)`.

Answer (score 3):

In swift it's:

```
let type = MyClass.self
```

to obtain the type from an instance instead:

```
var x = MyClass()
let type = x.dynamicType
```